# WSMAN and WMI System Properties

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, wql, wsman

I'm trying to retrieve __PATH property in WQL query.

When I trying to enumerate it using WSMAN and WQL query, it returns only ProcessId .

```
Get-WSManInstance -Enumerate wmicimv2/* -filter "SELECT __PATH, ProcessId FROM Win32_Process"
```

But it is easy to make sure that __PATH is not null.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT __PATH, ProcessId FROM Win32_Process"  -Namespace root/cimv2
```

Why it is not possible to retrieve WMI System Properties (like __PATH) in enumeration request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__PATH` is *WMI*-specific metadata.

A path (in WMI terminology) is a URL-*like* resource identifier that helps you locate a specific object.

WSMan does not share that concept, but describes resources by referencing a ResourceURI (or class name, in your case `wmicimv2/Win32_Process`), and one or more **key selectors** to distinguish a unique instance. The "path", as such, are really contained in these two pieces of information:

```
PS C:\> (Get-WSManInstance wmicimv2/Win32_Process -SelectorSet {Handle = 4}).Caption
System
```

Comment: you have to add @ to {Handle = 4}

Comment: I have asked this question on microsoft forum and received same question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38ce6e82-cbe5-44c7-98c5-9dc8a8701e9f/wsman-and-wmi-system-properties?forum=os_windowsprotocols

Comment: @John absolutely right, typo on my part. Please suggest an edit